# Склонение названия города

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь

"В городе Юрьев-Польский" — надо склонять или нет?

Answer (score 1):

Названия городов, сел, деревень, поселков, усадеб, выраженные склоняемым существительным (имя собственно Юрьев-Польский является таковым), как правило, согласуются в падеже с определяемым словом, например: в городе Москве, у города Смоленска, над городом Саратовом; в деревню Дюевку, через хутор Подбанку, в селе Ильинском.
Существуют исключения, так сказать, из общего правила. Не склоняются такие названия (не согласуются с определяемым словом), если: 1) имя собственное выражено словосочетанием (например, *в городе Кривой Рог*); 2) если название - это существительное в форме множественного числа (например, из города Черновцы, в городе Барановичи); 3) если род имени собственного не совпадает с родовым понятием (например, до города РОвно); 4) имя собственное заканчивается на -ово(-ёво), -ыно(-ино) – в городе Иваново, из поселка Пушкино. В вашем случае имя собственное слоняется: в городе Юрьеве-Польском (в словаре Ф.Л. Агеенко  "Собственные имена в русском языке" в названии Юрьев-Польский (вариант Юрьев-ПольскОй) склоняются обе части). Такая же информация есть на Грамоте.ру.

Answer (score 0):

Причём склонять оба слова?

Comment: Дополняю свой ответ, чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос.